# Problem changing background color in Xamarin form from View model

Tags: xamarin.forms, colors

Is there something different about changing the text value of an Entry, and the background color of an entry?

Using the code here...https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/app-compass.  I can add an entry

```
       <Entry Placeholder="Degree to follow:" 
               Text="{Binding Degree}"  x:Name="Degree" 
               Keyboard="Numeric" 
               Grid.Row="0"  BackgroundColor="Green"/>
```

In the ViewModel define a property

```
       public string _degree;
        public string Degree
        {
            get => _degree; 
            set => SetProperty(ref _degree, value); 
        }
```

I can change the Entry from the View Model..."_degree = "3333";"
I can get it's value..."HeadingDisplay = $"Heading: {Heading.ToString()}" + " Degree: " + _degree;"

Why then, can I not change the background color of one of the entry, label, or page the same way?
I added the binding here...

```
       <Label Grid.Row="2" 
            Text="{Binding HeadingDisplay}" 
           x:Name="LabelInfo"
              TextColor="{Binding BGColor, Mode=OneWay}" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

And then tried to change it in the ViewModel, I have tried a few different things...

```
        public Color BGColor { get; set; }

        //public Color BgColor
        //{
        //    get => _bgcolor;
        //    set => SetProperty(ref _bgcolor, value);
        //}
               //_bgcolor = "#00FF00;
                //_bgcolor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red;
                BGColor = Color.Red;
```

### The background color never changes.  Do I need a converter, does the page need to be re-displayed, or what?

As per comments below, I made some changes, I am now binding the label background, instead of the text background

```
        <Label Grid.Row="2" 
            Text="{Binding HeadingDisplay}" 
           x:Name="LabelInfo" BackgroundColor="{Binding=BGCOLOR Mode=OneWay}" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

In the view model, this is the code now

```
 public Color _bgcolor;
        public Color BGCOLOR
        {
            get => _bgcolor;
            set => SetProperty(ref _bgcolor, value);
        }

//set the color here
               _bgcolor = Color.Red;
```

Still no color change.  I am unclear on the comment about two color types.  Can you point me to link, or give example?  I have also tried sending FromHex.

Comment: Degree calls SetProperty, BGColor does not.  This is needed to fire the PropertyChanged event

Comment: Which one namespace is the Color (from your property)? The Xamarin has two Color types. You must be used the correct to bind with a View.

Comment: I edited the original posting to show changes.  When I tried to put new line here, it posted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample how to modify `Color` and `Text` of Control , you can refer to check where problem is .

Create a **ViewModel** class :

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Color color { set; get; }

    public Color Color
    {
        set
        {
            if (color != value)
            {
                color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return color;
        }
    }

    private string textValue { set; get; }

    public string TextValue
    {
        set
        {
            if (textValue != value)
            {
                textValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextValue");
            }
        }

        get { return textValue; }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        color = Color.Red;
        textValue = "Default Text";
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The **Xaml** code :

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="{Binding TextValue}" TextColor="{Binding Color}"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding TextValue}" TextColor="{Binding Color}"/>
    <Button Text="Change" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

In ContenPage can modify the value as follow :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ViewModel viewModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new ViewModel();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.TextValue = "New Value";
        viewModel.Color = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: As I stated above, I downloaded, and am trying to modify the code in .https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/app-compass.  That View model code does not have INotifyPropertyChanged, are you saying that I need to add it?  I am not understanding why I can change the entry value that I added, but not the background colors.

Comment: @Lou Yes , `INotifyPropertyChanged` is needed . Why background colors not work , maybe that's affected by other code . After all, it is a project created for achieve some other functions .